# MySQL performance issues in my mind

Tags: mysql, database, performance, server

First of all, I'm not a very experienced developer, I'm making mid-size apps in PHP, MySQL and Javascript.

There is something though which is making it hard for me to design a MySQL InnoDB database before each project. And that is the **performance.** I'm always quite worried about if I'm creating a normalized database scheme that when I'll have to join a couple of tables (like 5-6) together (there are usually a few many-to-many, many-to-one relationships between them) it will affect the performance a LOT (in negative) when each of these 5-6 tables has around 100k rows.

These projects that I usually have is creating analytics platforms. Therefore I'm expecting around 100M of clicks in total and I usually have to join this table to many others (each around 100k of rows) to get some data displayed. I'm usually making summarized tables of the clicks but cannot do the same for the other tables.

I'm not quite sure if I have to worry about future performance in this stage. Currently, I am actively managing a few of these applications with 30M+ clicks and tables that I join to this Clicks table with 40k+ rows. The performance is pretty bad - a select operation usually takes more than 10-20s to complete while I believe I have proper indexing, innodb_buffer_pool_size also.

I've read a lot about the key to having an optimized database is the design. That's why I'm usually thinking about the DB scheme a LOT before creating it.

Do I really have to worry about creating DB schemes where I'll have to Join 5-6 many-to-many/many-to-one/one-to-many tables or it's quite usual and MySQL should be able to easily handle this load?

Is there anything else that I should consider before creating a DB scheme?

My usual server setup is having a MySQL Server with 4GB RAM + 2 vCPUs,  to serve the DB and a WebServer with 4GB RAM + 2 vCPUs. Both of them are using Ubuntu's 16.04 release and using the latest MySQL (5.7.21) and PHP7-fpm.

Comment: Databases exist that support hundreds of millions of rows with reasonable performance.  4 GB of RAM seems quite small these days.  I might question your choice of technology.

Comment: You're describing `premature optimisation`. Maintainability, ease of testing, standard practices, etc, etc, are all more important than performance ***until*** you've actually demonstrated a performance issue. If you make compromises for performance too early you'll probably find you optimised the wrong area and something you hadn't considered is what really needs optimising, but your existing compromises have made that much, much harder. If you're dealing with Transactional Data, err heavily towards normalisation, if you're deal with with Analytics consider flat-file de-normalised structures.

Comment: Thanks for the detailed reply everyone!

Comment: Open up another Question to discuss the "tables you cannot summarize".  There may be some tricks.

Comment: If you want to pursue the poor performance of the Clicks JOIN, please provide `SHOW CREATE TABLE` and `SELECT`.

Comment: There is such a thing as "over-normalizing".  In particular, do _not_ normalize 'continuous' values, such as `FLOAT`, `DATETIME`.

Comment: See my [_tips on many-to-many_](http://mysql.rjweb.org/doc.php/index_cookbook_mysql#many_to_many_mapping_table)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Gordon is right. RDBMSs are made to handle your kind of workload.

If you're using virtual machines (cloud, etc) to host your stuff, you can generally increase your RAM, vCPU count, and IO capacity simply by spending more money.  But, usually, throwing money at DBMS peformance problems is less helpful than throwing better indexes at them.

At the scale of 100M rows, query performance is a legitimate concern. You will, as your project develops, need to revisit your DBMS indexing to optimize the queries you're actually using. So plan on that. The thing is, you cannot and will not know until you get lots of data what your actual performance issues will be.

Read this for a preview of what's coming:  https://use-the-index-luke.com/ .

One piece of advice: **partitioning** of tables generally doesn't solve performance problems except under very specific circumstances.

Look up this acronym:  YAGNI.

And go do your project. Spend your present effort getting it working.

Comment: Thanks for the detailed reply, understood! Gonna have to think about performance issues when they're there and try to get the applications live as soon as possible instead of thinking too much about later performance issues that I can't predict.

Comment: I agree, with one minor exception.  Since `ALTER TABLE` is a pain, think carefully about datatypes "prematurely".  Don't blindly use `BIGINT` and `TEXT` if `TINYINT UNSIGNED` and `VARCHAR(20)` are adequate for the foreseeable future.